# Accountability for famous people

Tags: criminal-law

If a heavily famous person (let's suppose a famous football player [I don't call it soccer]) kills an other ordinary civilian  and there's proof of such an act, will he get away with his crime, realistically talking, by simply being wealthy or will he be landed to jail like everyone else?

Comment: That really depends on the culture and the country. In many countries: the richer you are the better the evidence needs to be to have you convicted, but if the evidence is good, you are going to jail. Different rules apply in dictatorships or countries where laws are easily bent to suit the powers at be. And interesting example is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O._J._Simpson_murder_case

Comment: To whit, O.J. Simpson was incarcerated for the duration of his murder trial which was the most lengthy criminal trial in U.S. History.   There's quite a few cases of U.S. sports stars getting arrested for and standing trial for Murder and other crimes.  The most recent example was a New England (Play in Boston but the geographic area represents several states) Patriots player who was convicted of Murder a few years back

Comment: Given the clarifications the op has made in chat and in response to my answer, this question is essentially unanswerable due to the criteria and limitations the op is applying, so therefore I am voting to close.

Comment: Ray Lewis, an actually footballer, was charged with and acquitted of murder.  Did he get away with a double homicide?  Some feel that he did.

Answer (score 1):

A rich person can afford the most expensive defence lawyers. The most expensive defence lawyers can find evidence that a cheaper lawyer might miss. They should be better at finding previous cases that are beneficial to the case. They should be better at convincing a jury that there is doubt about your guilt than a cheaper lawyer. And the cheaper lawyer, working full time on your case, will be more likely to be able to help you than a lawyer paid by the state who covers many more cases.

If the rich person committed a crime and there is good evidence, their lawyer can't bend the law and get them off the hook that way. Money can still help you. If you punched me in the face, and I had the choice: I can call the police and report it and you go to jail for six months, or I take a million dollars and keep quiet. Most people would take the money. (A good lawyer will be able to tell Mr. Rich what he can do *legally* to get out of trouble, what would be illegal, and what they can get away with).

In Germany and other countries, to make sure rich people can't just pay their way out of problems, minor offences like causing a traffic accident may get you a conviction for example for "20 day sentences". Which means you have the choice of going to jail for 20 days, or paying 20 days income (and not your "official" income, but your real income). So Bill Gates would have to pay an amount of money that is just as painful for him as the much smaller payment I would have to make would be for me.

Comment: Just being able to hire your own lawyer instead of relying on the public defender is a huge advantage, not because public defenders are bad lawyers but because public defenders are usually overworked and thus have a tendency to advise plea deals to get cases off their docket.

Comment: Paying someone not to report a crime is itself a crime. That said, it happens all the time.

Comment: @DaleM I suppose it's hard to prove that A paid victim B not to report a crime, instead of B not reporting it because he didn't want anyone to go to jail, and A giving B a huge present because he is grateful and ashamed of his actions.

Comment: @gnasher729 in many countries, it’s a crime not to report a crime.

Comment: @DaleM In many situations it makes your life a lot saver.

Comment: @gnasher729 I strongly object to the start of this answer **"The most expensive defence lawyers can find evidence that a cheaper lawyer might miss"**. Do you know what discovery is? The courtroom isn't a TV drama where new evidence is sprong on the opposing party for shock value. A courtroom is for two parties to argue what the facts are. Both parties have access to the same evidence.

Comment: @User37849012643 a defence lawyer with a staff of 20 can pursue a lot more avenues of investigation of the evidence than a defence lawyer acting on their own with another 20 cases to also cover that week.  The cheaper lawyer might not find the person who can prove the alibi, or the expert witness that can disprove some item of evidence, or the case law which throws something out etc etc etc.

Comment: @Moo The trope of "I've never hired an expert witness that disagreed with me" is completely true, but I was not and am not arguing that point, I'm arguing the fairness of processing evidence and information.

Comment: There are many rules in place that protect against discovery problems, either that be burdensome discovery to ethical opinions on when a lawyer should terminate representation do to financial or capability reasons. Don't quote me on this but I believe this could fall under Strickland's rule if the defense lawyer truly has twenty other cases.

Comment: @User37849012643 but you’ve hired an expert witness who has disagreed with the other side, surely?  The point is, the better funded defence lawyer can afford to spend significantly more time and resource on the case - facts are facts, sure, but they can be nuanced and disproven by other facts when tested.  And that doesn’t magically happen.

Comment: @Moo if you re-read my original comment I didn't argue that personal lawyers couldn't tip the scale, I point out the **exact** point of the answer I took issue with.

Comment: @User37849012643 and I’m disagreeing with your all too exact interpretation of the point - evidence can take many forms, and it doesn’t just need to be the evidence entered during discovery - disproval of the other sides evidence with new facts or case law could equally fall under the usage in the answer.  This is why we have an actual trial rather than just discovery and then sentencing...

Answer (score 1):

Given the number of Premier League players in the UK arrested and prosecuted for various relatively (to your example) minor criminal acts over the years, including driving under the influence of alcohol, speeding, assault, sexual offences etc, I think there would be no problem prosecuting them in the UK for murder.

Examples include:

- [Adam Johnson](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2019/mar/22/adam-johnson-former-sunderland-player-released-from-prison) - jailed for 6 years for child sex offences.
- [Various Premier League footballers](https://www.mirror.co.uk/sport/football/news/premier-league-footballers-saunders-jailed-16517808) jailed for various offences.

Other general examples include:

- [Lord Jeffery Archer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffrey_Archer) - a senior politician, worldwide successful author, jailed for perjury
- [Jonathan Aitkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Aitken) - politician, jailed for perjury
- [Fiona Onasanya](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-cambridgeshire-47040912) - Member of Parliament, jailed for perverting the course of justice
- [Gary Glitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gary_Glitter) - singer, entertainer, jailed for child sex offences
- [Fred Talbot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fred_Talbot) - famous TV personality, failed for indecent assault
- [Max Clifford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Clifford) - major UK political publicist, jailed for sexual offences

Obviously this is just for the UK jurisdiction.

Comment: My example was about heavily famous and skilled football players (Ronaldo, Messi, Balotelli, Zlatan). I was not mentioning every  player playing in a major league, but that's my fault I did not specify, you answered accordingly.

Comment: @abdul several of the players in the examples given are of the level you want - Ian Wright, Joey Barton, Eric Cantona etc etc etc.  I can add more examples if you want, such as Wayne Rooney, Vinnie Jones etc.

Comment: Take the former UK minister Chris Huhne. His wife took the blame when he was accused of speeding. Then they got divorced and she told the police as revenge. Both went to jail for perverting the course of justice. To avoid a speeding fine.

Comment: The UK judicial system has no problems prosecuting famous or influential people, indeed it seems to revel in it 

Comment: In Spain or Italy these kind of things don't occur, maybe because the systems are sneaky. Here in Italy if a rich person and a poor person engage in a dispute (not necessarily famous), be sure that the poor person will be taking the blame no matter what proofs the poor has in favour

Comment: Generally I have a tendency to think that rich and famous people could get away even with murder, but again, this is only my  conception, it could be otherwise for socially just countries such as Denmark, Sweden, Norway or Finland, but definitely it is the case in the USA and Italy, which do not care so much about actual justice, rather they do care only about dismissing the case as soon as possible, leading to inevitably blaming the poor and case closed. I have a tendency to this thought, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @abdul Phil Spector is in jail for murder right now, and is extremely famous within the music sphere. Prosecuted and jailed in the US.

Comment: @abdul Bill Cosby, currently in jail in the US...  shall I continue?

Comment: Thanks for the evidence...but these famous people are people I don't even know....I mean something who's famous to the extent of having 100 million followers on Instagram worldwide. You can mention me any UK or Canada minister, but I don't consider them as famous (unless it's Boris Johnson) because they're not known worldwide. I mean, yeah, as you proved to me, some famous people may undergo judicial process, but I found these famous people only as "moderately famous". A person with 20 million $ can go in prison, but I doubt that someone with 800 millions can go to jail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102820/discussion-between-moo-and-abdul).

Comment: @abdul You mentioned lots of football players. Football players are not famous. And someone with 800 millions can obviously go to jail if they punch someone with 1600 millions.

Comment: @abdul your question is essentially completely opinion based at this point, given your definitions of what you consider to be famous.

Comment: I'm satisfied with the answer

Comment: Being CEO of Samsung doesn't protect you from jail (Lee Jae-yong).

Comment: @gnasher729 Epstein....

Comment: Princess Anne of the UK Royal family, convicted and fined.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to use google and found this lovely site:

https://www.theclever.com/20-billionaires-who-ended-up-in-jail/

Number eight on the list: Bernie Madoff. 
Jeffrey Epstein supposedly had a wealth of $2 billion, so he didn't make it on the list. But he shows that having more than $800 million not only doesn't keep you out of jail, sometimes it doesn't even guarantee you get out alive.

And then there are Domenico Dolce & Stefano Gabbana, convicted for tax evasion. Probably the most well-known names on the list in Europe and USA, possible excepting Madoff and Epstein.

But richest man in jail is Eike Batista, once worth $30 billion.